# How to use Ipython console in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ipython

I am new to VSCode and have been trying to find a way to enable an Ipython console. I can see that there is an extension called 'ipython' by Hoang Kim Lai but upon installing this I cannot seem to find a way of getting it to produce an Ipython console. I have also tried using pip but I cannot get it to work this way either. I am aware that people have asked similar questions before but a lot of them seem to be referring to Jupyter notebooks where this is not what I want. I just need the Ipython console.

When trying to use the extension I expected some kind of instruction on how to set it up but I didn't received any. When trying to use pip it just results in saying 'The term 'ipython' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The easiest way is to run `ipython` console command in Terminal. [You can install ipython as any Python package in your virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/). Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa when I type ```ipython``` in the console I get the message 'The term 'ipython' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.'

Comment: https://ipython.org/install.html

Comment: If the installation of IPython does not work, please open another question with detailed steps of commands you use to install IPython and test if it works or not.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I have found the issue. I was using powershell rather than the command prompt. When using the command prompt it seems to work. Why is this the issue?

Comment: When you say "IPython console", do you mean like [the one in Spyder](//docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/ipythonconsole.html)? (I've never used it myself, but that's the first thing that came up when I googled it.) Or do you mean an IPython *shell*, running in a terminal? If it's the Spyder one, I don't know if there's a direct equivalent, but Jupyter is pretty close, so what's wrong with that? If it's the terminal one, try `python -m IPython` and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

> The term 'ipython' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program

Please find the path where you installed ipython on your computer and add the path to the **PATH** environment variable.